# Laravel Websanova/Vue-Auth Login/Register Returning Undefined URL

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, single-page-application, middleware

So, I'm learning how to create Single Page Applications using Laravel & Vue.js, and I found this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ripoche.b/create-a-spa-with-role-based-authentication-with-laravel-and-vue-js-ac4b260b882f). I followed everything, I didn't change anything but I keep getting this undefined whenever I will login/register

I've double-triple checked everything.

Image showing the http://127.0.0.1:8080/undefined/api/auth/login -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCOn5.jpg

Here's the code:

***Auth.js***

```
import bearer from '@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer'
import axios from '@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x'
import router from '@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x'
// Auth base configuration some of this options
// can be override in method calls
const config = {
auth: bearer,
http: axios,
router: router,
tokenDefaultName: 'recipe-lists',
tokenStore: ['localStorage'],
rolesVar: 'role',
registerData: {url: "auth/register", method: 'POST', redirect: '/login'},
loginData: {url: "auth/login", method: 'POST', redirect: '/', fetchUser: true},
logoutData: {url: "auth/logout", method: 'POST', redirect: '/', makeRequest: true},
fetchData: {url: "auth/user", method: 'GET', enabled: true},
refreshData: {url: "auth/refresh", method: 'GET', enabled: true, interval: 30}
}
export default config
```

api.php

```php
Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('refresh', 'Auth\AuthController@refresh');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
Route::get('user', 'Auth\AuthController@user');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
});
});
```

login.vue

```
<script>
export default {
data() {
return {
email: null,
password: null,
has_error: false,
isProcessing: false,
}
},
methods: {
login() {
// Get the redirect object
this.isProcessing = true
var redirect = this.$auth.redirect()
this.$auth.login({
body: {
email: this.email,
password: this.password
},
success: function() {
// Handle Redirection
const redirectTo = redirect ? redirect.from.name : this.$auth.user().role === 2 ? 'admin.dashboard' : 'dashboard'
this.$router.push('/')
},
error: function() {
this.has_error = true
},
rememberMe: true,
fetchUser: true
})
}
}
}
</script>
```

Can someone explain to me what's happening pretty noob here.

Thank you!

I expected the url to be http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/auth/login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem with the `undefined` part in URL.

The reason was that I did not have the `MIX_APP_URL` variable set up in my `.env` Laravel configuration file.
The way `${process.env.MIX_APP_URL}` works is that an environment variable can be injected by Node at runtime, in this case the application url.

One reason we want the `MIX_APP_URL` in `.env` is that any developer using your application can easily set it up and only modify the `MIX_APP_URL` variable.

The other, very important reason is that the URL **will** differ for a local server and for production - in this case the solution to change it to a static URL would not work and would be prone to an error in a production environment.

One thing to notice though, when running the NPM `watch` task, the change of an `.env` variable does not apply immediately, the `watch` task **has to be restarted**.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my error was from my **app.js**, the code is:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = `${process.env.MIX_APP_URL}/api`
```

After I changed it to:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api`
```

It worked, the undefined thingy is now gone. I didn't know why the first one didn't work but meh.

Reddit user /u/mrcat323 helped me get an answer in /r/vuejs.

Comment: Did you find out why the first option is not working?